# Assembling a c string and returning it by reference (using malloc and string.h functions)

Tags: c, string, http, malloc, strcat

I want to assemble some sort of a HTTP header (its just a fun project im doing). But my problem is more about on how to do that in C. I have a function like this:

```
void assembleResponse(char **response, const unsigned short code, const unsigned long length, const char *contentType)
{
    char *status;
    char *server = {"Server: httpdtest\r\n"};
    char *content = malloc(17 + strlen(contentType));
    char *connection = {"Connection: close"};

    printf("AA");

    strcpy(content, "Content-type: ");
    strcat(content, contentType);
    strcat(content, "\r\n");

    printf("BB");

    switch (code)
    {
    case 200:
       //200 Ok
       status = malloc(sizeof(char) * 18);
       //snprintf(status, 17, "HTTP/1.1 200 Ok\r\n");
       strcpy(status, "HTTP/1.1 200 Ok\r\n");
       break;
    }

    printf("CC");

    unsigned int len = 0;
    len += strlen(status);
    len += strlen(server);
    len += strlen(content);
    len += strlen(connection);

    printf("DD");

    response = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 5));
    strcpy(*response, status);
    strcat(*response, server);
    strcat(*response, content);
    strcat(*response, connection);
    strcat(*response, "\r\n\r\n");

    printf("EE");
}
```

And somewhere in main I want to make a response like so:

```
char *resp;
assembleResponse(&resp, 200, 500, "text/html");
printf("assembled response: %s", resp);
```

But I dont quite get there :) There seem to be a lot of problems on how Im allocating the strings and inserting content into them. I get to the "BB" flag but further on I get:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x104b10e88: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? I am familliar with `malloc` and C-like functions but clearly not an expert with them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem seems to be here:

```
response = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 5));
```

In this case you are allocating an array of `char*` with incorrect size.

You should do:

```
*response = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 5));
```

in order to allocate an array of `char`.